# Barba.js Transition Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, barbajs

I am experimenting on Barba.js. What i am trying to do is when transitioning from page to page, i want to see the animation of 3 colour-pages to load up first as a canvas effect. Unfortunately, only the first canvas happens on load but the other three are non-existent. I tried a few combinations in main.js, i show you one of them.

You can see this live [here](https://codepen.io/nikmors/project/editor/ZjwMkk)

```
$(function () {
    barba.init({
        sync: true,

        transitions: [
            {
                async leave(data) {
                    const done = this.async();

                    pageTransition();
                    await delay(1000);


                    pageTransitionTwo();
                    await delay(1000);


                    pageTransitionThree();
                    await delay(1000);
                    done();
                },

                async enter(data) {
                    contentAnimation();
                },

                async once(data) {
                    contentAnimation();
                },
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

How can i run loading-screen-one, loading-screen-two & loading-screen-three with a difference delay, the one after the other with barba.js?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood you correctly, your page transition consists of some overlay changing its color 3 times, but it is only changing its color once?

If so, i think the problem is that you are calling `done()` already after 1000 milliseconds because of your first call of `await delay(1000)`. Calling done will basically tell Barba that the next Page can be loaded into the DOM and the rest of your code in `leave()` is probably not being executed.

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

```
transitions: [{
    name: 'transition-name',
    async leave(data) {
        const done = this.async();

                changePage();
                await delay(1000);
                done()
    },
    async enter(data) {
        
    //    return enterAnimation()
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Explain how it works for you, give some detail